# Grunt serve Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.( revisited)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yo

I have been trying to test out the Web App generator on my Win 10 64-bit Dev machine, so I open a PS Shell command window and followed these steps

```
 // 1. Install core of yeoman
 npm install -g yo
 // Wait until yeoman installation is completed
 // 2. Install bower
npm install -g bower
// Wait until bower installation is completed
// 3. Install Grunt Client
 npm install -g grunt-cli
// Wait until grunt client installation is completed
// 4. Install the first generator
npm install -g generator-webapp

  *npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before
  will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as
  soon as possible*.

 // if I temporarily "ignore" the error and carry on..... 
 // note I notice my npm version was old so altered the system path and now 
 // 3.8.7

mkdir test
cd test
yo WebApp

grunt serve

A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started
guide for  more information on how to configure grunt: 
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
```

Oh great!

Did a bit of searching out found this 
http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/gruntjs/grunt/q/stackoverflow/15483735/quotfatal-error-unable-to-find-local-grunt-quot-when-running-quotgruntquot-comma

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
jshint: {
  files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'App/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
  options: {
    globals: {
      jQuery: true
    }
  }
 },
watch: {
  files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
  tasks: ['jshint']
  }
  });

 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

 grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

 };
```

Now I hit this error ( I know the Serve task isn't defined )

grunt serve
   Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.

At this point I thought I do now need to ask the community ;-). Maybe I need to verify the versions of Bower etc installed

Daniel

Comment: When you use `yo webapp` it will create a directory called webapp. You have to use `cd webapp` then `grunt serve` inside it. Otherwise, please post the full content of your gruntfile.js

Comment: @Ahmad .Thanks for replying.  I have checked the my demo dir and there is no webapp dir, although there is a App dir which looks a like a mini web site.  I have posted the full grunfile.js which I had to create in the first place as it wasn't generated.  Do you want to see the  package.json.

Answer (score 1):

The new generator-webapp doesn't use grunt anymore. There were several changes on the generator. The new generator-webapp now use gulp.

Please check the installation documentation on:
[generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp)

Comment: This is correct, you must use `gulp serve` in the current latest version of **generator-webapp**